# Using WebBrowser in ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service, webbrowser-control

I am trying to use a WebBrowser in a .cs class in a Web Application - NOT A WINDOWS FORM app using (VS 2019).
I know it's a Windows Form app control, but it seems like I should be able to use it in a Web App.

Using WebBrowser in Web App does not have the .Url property, so I just use the .Navigate directly - this is where the code breaks.

I have tried many suggestions on the Net, but nothing seems to work - it looks like most of the examples uses a Web Page - I want to use the WebBrowser directly in code (.cs class).

private static void LoginViaUserAgentFlow()
        {

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(delegate ()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.Format("{0}/services/oauth2/authorize",
                RHOutlook.chosenInstance.sfdcURL));

            sb.Append("?response_type=token");
            sb.Append(String.Format("&client_id={0}", RHOutlook.chosenInstance.clientId));
            sb.Append(String.Format("&redirect_uri={0}", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(RHOutlook.chosenInstance.redirectUri)));

            WebBrowser webBrowserSFDCLogin = new WebBrowser();


            //Here I can't use the .Url becaue it is not available - so I just use 
            //Navigate to get to the site
            webBrowserSFDCLogin.Url = new Uri(sb.ToString());

            //This is were it breaks, comes back with error when I navigate to the site.
            webBrowserSFDCLogin.Navigate(sb.ToString());


            //This code is never reached - failed at above code.
            if (webBrowserSFDCLogin.LocationURL != null && webBrowserSFDCLogin.LocationURL.StartsWith(RHOutlook.chosenInstance.redirectUri))
            {
                //webBrowserSFDCLogin.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                webBrowserSFDCLogin.Stop();
            }
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
    }
```

I expect to be able to navigate to the external website. If I can navigate to the site if I copy the url directly in a browser (say Chrome).

I tried using ; this gives me the Url property, but still get the error.

Comment: You really want to reconsider **NOT** using `WebBrowser` class.

Answer (score 0):

**You really should stick to suggestions and examples.**

*What you are trying to do is to use class that is designed for Windows Application inside a Web Application.*

**Those two frameworks are similar like Earth and Mars. I am afraid you are not going to be able to grow a tree on Mars.**